# Simple like SQL statement failed

Tags: mysql, sql-like

I know this might shock some but I just cant figure out what's wrong with this SQL statement.. it kills my head.

```
SELECT * FROM groups WHERE gname LIKE '%m%';
```

I am using mysql 5.1.41

Comment: What is wrong? It would be useful to know what you expect and what you are getting.

Comment: what error message do you get?  what happens when you execute this?  read this: http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html

Comment: @ChrisCM the query should return all rows that have a letter m on column gname

Comment: @duffymo i dont get any error...the return is blank

Comment: are you sure that you have gnames with lower case 'm' in them?  if you don't get anything back, maybe you don't have any data that meets the where clause.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't get any rows back, perhaps that's the right answer.  Mistakes usually happen when your assumptions don't match the situation at hand.

Are you sure you have values in the gname column with lower case 'm' in them?

Are you sure you're running the query against the database you think you are?

Comment: have already solved it, thnx duffymo. the problem was in the xter case...my values are in UPPERCASE ;)

Comment: If I were you, I'd acknowledge ChrisCM by voting the answer up.  I'd argue that s/he solved it, not you.

Comment: :) my bad - Thnx ChrisCM & duffymo. ;)

Answer (score 1):

This statement will retrieve every column and every row from the groups table where the gname column contains a lowercase m somewhere. Is this what you wanted to achieve?

Comment: thanx, ive seen it - my values (gname) are in Capital and i was comparing it with lower case m. Thnx ChrisCM